# SQL Server - Delete records from multiple related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 related tables called `tblResponse` and `tblUser`, I want to delete records from `tblUser` which have a value of `inactive` in the status column.

In the `tblResponse` table, I also want to delete all these records whose `UserId` from `tblUser` have been deleted.

Each `UserId` potentially has multiple responses in `tblResponse` table, it needs to delete all of them.

This jobs needs to run everyday.

```
 DELETE A
 FROM tblUser A
 INNER JOIN tblUser U ON UserId = EmployeeID
 WHERE UserStatus = 'Inactive'
```

In the above query `UserId` is from `tblUser` and `EmployeeID` is from `tblResponse`.

How can I delete the data from 2 tables ?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how can i delete the data from 2 tables

Comment: Set up a foreign key constraint (w/ cascading deletes) when creating the Response table.  That's what they're for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to handle this is to set up the tables with a foreign key constraint, where the `ON DELETE` is set to `CASCADE`:

```
CREATE TABLE Users 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ... other fields
)

CREATE TABLE Responses 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1, 1),
    UserID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Users (ID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE  -- when UserID updated, update this UserID also
        ON DELETE CASCADE, -- when User deleted, delete these rows also
    ... other fields
)
```

This is of course the preferred method because it instructs the database to maintain its own integrity without requiring the application layers to handle it.

Occasionally this cannot be done though, either due to pre-existing tables with bad data (where we should then consider cleaning the data then applying the constraint), or possible circular constraints, in which case you have to use two delete statements:

```
-- remove the associated responses first
DELETE r
FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN Responses AS r ON u.ID = r.UserID
WHERE u.Active = 0;

-- then delete your users
DELETE FROM Users WHERE Active = 0;
```

Comment: Transacting the multiple deletes might be to maintain data integrity.

Comment: will we face any issue in future if we go without using foreignkey constraint and delete using multiple deletes ?

Comment: Data integrity is the only real issue, but that can be a very big issue if left unchecked.  FK constraints are typically much preferred, but a sound education on database design would arm you with the ability to best answer your question (e.g., hard for me to say for sure)

Comment: Thank you, in that case i feel it is best to create a foreign key constraint on the table..